# TextField Valdiation in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

How can i Valdiate my TextField in Titanium or in JavaScript to restrict it to numbers only.

```
var txt_appt2 = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    top:2,
    left:240,
    width:75,
    color:'#000',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    font: {fontSize: 12}
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
```

to the TextField.

See example at http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2011/04/06/titanium-limit-the-characters-in-a-textfield/

Comment: solution is better, but i do not think it will prohibit the user from pasting invalid characters into the field

Comment: In iphone you are able to change the keyboard and input characters. I also believe you will be able to introduce spaces between the numbers in android

Answer (score 9):

```
txt_appt2.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    txt_appt2.value = txt_appt2.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/,"");
});
```

Comment: this solution, for me, is triggering the change event once you update the value. This will cause a unwanted loop.

Comment: It's because you're setting the value to the text field right away and it's triggering the same event over and over. Try setting the value by doing "e.source.value = ...." from within the event listener block.

It's just easier to create a global validation method and call it from XML or when you dynamically build the UI. i.e: 

`onChange="Alloy.Globals.validation.validateFloatField"`


 `Alloy.Globals.validation = {
    validateFloatField : function (e) {
         var input = e.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
         e.source.value = input;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering why they are experiencing continuous loops and errors;

The problem isn't listening to the onChange event. That's the proper event since it fires every time the value is changed. I.e. Copy and paste, keypress and so on.

On iOS users can copy and paste in characters even though you're only limiting to decimal / numeric keyboard.

Avoid trying to set the field value directly by referencing the text field property itself. Instead, use the text field property returned when the text field is changed. Doing it this way won't cause the onChange event to keep firing causing a never-ending loop.

**// XML**

```
<TextField keyboardType="Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_DECIMAL_PAD" value="0.00" onChange="Alloy.Globals.helper.decimalFormat" />
```

**// Alloy.js**

```
Alloy.Globals.helper = {
    decimalFormat: function(e) {
        // Strip all characters from the input except digits
        var input = e.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
        e.source.value = input;
    }
};
```